# How to group Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex columns?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex column Pandas DataFrame A:

```
       foo    
       bar   baz
s1_a     1     2
s1_b     3     4
s2_a     5     6
s2_b     7     8
```

I want to group the data on a key from another DataFrame B:

```
       key
s1_a     1
s1_b     1
s2_a     2
s2_b     2
```

For a DataFrame without a MultiIndex, I would do:

```
pd.merge(A, B, left_index=True, right_index=True).groupby('key').sum()
```

but this does not work with the MultiIndex. The desired result is

```
    foo
    bar    baz
1     4      6
2    12     14
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series can be passed to `groupby` directly and the grouper will do appropriate index alignment, so it is possible to do:

```
A.groupby(B['key']).sum()
```

```
    foo    
    bar baz
key        
1     4   6
2    12  14
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = ['s1_a', 's1_b', 's2_a', 's2_b']
A = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(1, 9).reshape((-1, 2)),
    index=idx,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo'], ['bar', 'baz']])
)

B = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 1, 2, 2]}, index=idx)
```

---

Note this will work in many cases but is less durable than merging:

`B` variant 1:

```
B = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 2]}, index=['s1_a', 's1_b', 's2_b'])
      key
s1_a    1  # No s2_a
s1_b    2
s2_b    2


A.groupby(B['key']).sum()

    foo    
    bar baz
key        
1.0   1   2
2.0  10  12
```

`B` variant 2:

```
B = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 1, 2, 2]}, index=['s1_a', 's2_a', 's1_b', 's2_b'])
      key
s1_a    1
s2_a    1  # s1_a/s2_a together
s1_b    2
s2_b    2  # s1_b/s2_b together

A.groupby(B['key']).sum()

    foo    
    bar baz
key        
1     6   8
2    10  12
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know you could pass a Series to groupby(). This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can subset the level and restore is after the `merge` using `pandas.concat`:

```
C = pd.concat({'foo': (pd.merge(A['foo'], B, left_index=True, right_index=True)
                         .groupby('key')
                         .sum()
                       )
              }, axis=1)
```

output:

```
>>> C
    foo    
    bar baz
key        
1     4   6
2    12  14
```

*NB. technically, the code you used should work with a `FutureWarning`, however you lose the MultiIndex an get tuples instead*

```
>>> pd.merge(A, B, left_index=True, right_index=True).groupby('key').sum()
     (foo, bar)  (foo, baz)
key                        
1             4           6
2            12          14

FutureWarning: merging between different levels is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (2 levels on the left,1 on the right)
```